# How can I speed up the rendering of my WPF ListBox?

Tags: wpf, performance, user-interface, listbox

I have a WPF ListBox control [(view code)](http://github.com/jcbozonier/alloy/blob/2e82343b4b0739eb32ff3fd63354decbe08fc452/IronTwit/Alloy/Alloy.UI/Views/MainView.xaml) and I am keeping maybe like 100-200 items in it. Every time the ObservableCollection it is bound to changes though it takes it a split second to update and it freezes the whole UI. Is there a way to add elements incrementally or something I can do to improve the performance of this control?

Answer (score 2):

Try something where (PanelList is a ListBox or something);

```
new Task(delegate {
   foreach (var info in new DirectoryInfo("C:\\windows\\system32").EnumerateFiles()) {
       PanelList.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)delegate {
          PanelList.Items.Add(info);
       });
       Thread.Sleep(0);
   }
}).Start();
```

You want to run a background task and update a UI control incrementally through Dispatcher.Invoke, make sure to set your priority relativly low, and I always throw a sleep in just for fun (voluntarially context swap), also you should be checking if your current task has been canceled...

Oh ya, this is not so much a performance improvement as precieved performance and UI responsiveness.

Comment: This approach was exactly what I needed.  Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" on your ListBox - [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx). Also see this [blog post](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/ralph/Blog/archive/2007/07/09/wpf-filtering-a-listview.aspx) I came across. I haven't tried it personally, but it seems like a good place to start. Good luck!